# Leaflet and leaflet.editable save properties like types and other information

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have added a color to leaflet with editable using this code

```
function pl (latlng, options) {
    const p = map.editTools.startPolygon(latlng, {
        ...options, ...{ color: 'red' }
    })
    return p
}

L.NewPolygonControl = L.EditControl.extend({
    options: {
        position: 'topleft',
        callback: pl,
        kind: 'polygon',
        html: '▰'
    }
});
```

How can I add information like color and other information to the properties of `toGeoJSON`?